# Pyinstaller - windows closed immediately when run the program

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I just converted .Py and successfully generated .exe file. When tried to launch,the application windows immediately closed without any error.

Found same question from internet but there is no exact solution provided. I'm using python 3.4 on windows 7 32 bit.

May I know what went wrong with the program?

Comment: Run your .exe from the command line to show the error.